# Is it okay to use Present Perfect Tense right after "to see how"?

Tags: grammar, phrases

Is it okay to use Present Perfect Tense right after "to see how"?

For example,

> It is both sad and funny to see how these guys have never really got
>   to the core of the matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is okay. It might seem that the verb tenses of "see" and "have ... got" don't agree, but "see" is an [infinitve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitive), and because it is an infinitive, it:

> They do not have tense, aspect, moods, and/or voice, or they are limited in the range of tenses, aspects, moods, and/or voices that they can use

Thus, they do not have to agree with the verb of the sentence in tense.